# Create a mock request object for testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

got surprisingly stuck on this, I'm trying to create some test cases for my function that takes a request and parses the JSON with get_json. But keep getting errors on get_json as "str object" "byte object" doesn't have get_json. How do I create a mock request object that I give to my function?

Test

```
class TestX:
    def test_encrypt_url_missing_request_data(self):
        # Arrange
        request_json = {
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "content": {
                "email": "test@test.com"
            }                
        }    
        
        # Act
        res = encrypt_url(json.dumps(request_json, indent=4))

        # Assure
        assert res == 'user_id or email parameter missing',400
```

Beginning of function causing the issue

```
#entry point for request
def encrypt_url(request):

    request_json = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 0):

This call doesn't make sense:

```
encrypt_url(json.dumps(request_json, ... ))
```

since `.dumps()` will produce a `str`
rather than a request or a request-like object.
If you choose to go the mocking route,
then it's up to you to implement that.
Use something like

```
encrypt_url(MockRequest(json.dumps(request_json, ... )))
```

and then you're still on the hook for
implementing that new class.
Its constructor will accept a string,
and at a minimum the class must offer
a `def get_json(self):` function.